# Некорректная работа селектора для CheckBox'ов в CheckBoxPreference

Tags: xml, android, checkbox

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла необходимость поправить чекбоксы в приложении, а именно: изменить изображения.   Немного погуглив, наткнулся на решение. Итак, в теме приложения прописываем

```
<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxStyle</item>
```

далее создаем стиль

```
<style name="CheckBoxStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/checkbox_pink</item>
</style>
```

и для завершения селектор:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_grey" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_grey" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_pink" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_pink" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_pink"/>

</selector>
```

Все это дело решил проверить. Запускаю приложение, а все чекбоксы в "выключеном состоянии", а само переключение состояний не работает. Для уверенности в корректной работе селектора я взял стандартный селектор `\sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res\drawable\btn_check.xml` и заменил свой на тот, что любезно предоставил Google. Заменив все ресурсы, снова запустил приложение. Результат один и тот же. Не пашет и все. Есть ли какие-то причины некорректной работы селекторов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя неделю нашел аналогичный вопрос, решением было переименование файлов с селекторами.
p.s. в эклипсе Alt+Shift+R на выбранном файле. Надеюсь, что кому-нибудь еще поможет.